# Can vue import path be specified to have multiple starting point?

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue.js. I am studying someone's code. There are two files, lets' say src/a/b.vue and src/c/d.js. The import statement in src/a/b.vue is simply

```
import {b} from 'c/d'
```

When I use the same statement, I will get an error complaining c/d.js can't be found in src/a.
I guess there is some config or compiling flags. How could I debug the problem? I can use `yarn serve` on the old project and my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an alias for "src" fodler and then your import paths will look like this:

```
import {b} from '@/c/d'
```

If you use Vite, the alias is already defined by default. You can find it in vite.config

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), vueJsx()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)) // this is an alias
    }
  }
})
```

Please provide information which version of Vue do you use. And do you use Vite or something else?

Comment: Thank you. In packages.json, I see the my vue version is 2.6.14, while the working one uses 2.5.2. There is no Vite definition is both package.json. There are quite some sources use the syntax. If possible, I hope I can keep the source un-changed.

Comment: The above info is not correct. It seems I should use "npm list vue" to check the used vue version. The working one is 2.6.12, while the bad one is 2.7.x. I am not sure if that is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

It seems if I use the same yarn.lock for exactly the same package version and then use the same vue.config.js file, the issue is gone. It may be related to package version. I saw the working vue version is 2.6.12.